# How do I create a new column to my data frame that pulls and reorders the data from another column?

Tags: python

I have a data frame with a column that has both first and last names. I need to somehow create another column that basically concatenates the names as such:

John Smith ---------------------------------> smithjo01

Where basically the first five letters of their last name and the first two of their first name come together. Then they're given a number starting with 01. If they are the second person with that same name they are given 02, and so forth.

Also, if their last name only has four or less letters, they include all the possible letters and use the first name like normal. For example:

Peter Pan ---------------------------------> panpe01

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Full Code**

```
import pandas as pd

data = ({
    'Name': ["John Smith", "Peter Pan", "John Smith", "Peter Pan", "John Smith", "Peter Pan", "John Smith", "Peter Pan", "John Smith", "Peter Pan",],
})
# Converting data to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['FirstName', 'LastName']] = df.Name.str.split(expand=True)
# Combining Last name and 2 leters of First name
df["UID"] = df["LastName"].astype(
    str).str.lower()+df["FirstName"].astype(str).str.lower().str[:2]

df["UID"] = df["UID"] + \
    df.groupby('UID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.zfill(
        2)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         Name FirstName LastName        UID
0  John Smith      John    Smith  smithjo01
1   Peter Pan     Peter      Pan    panpe01
2  John Smith      John    Smith  smithjo02
3   Peter Pan     Peter      Pan    panpe02
4  John Smith      John    Smith  smithjo03
5   Peter Pan     Peter      Pan    panpe03
6  John Smith      John    Smith  smithjo04
7   Peter Pan     Peter      Pan    panpe04
8  John Smith      John    Smith  smithjo05
9   Peter Pan     Peter      Pan    panpe05
```

Hope this helps. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. One last thing. The current column has both first and last name, I don't have two columns that have them separated. Any way I can do this with how that's set up?

It looks like you have two columns in your example, when I have one column with names made out like "John Smith"

Comment: Also, I need to start out with the first name being "smithjo01"...I can't have one that is just "smithjo"

Comment: I have changed the code according to your needs.